# Generate Javascript by using C# dynamically in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Is there any better way to generate Javascript by using C# dynamically in ASP.NET?

Now I'm doing like this:

C#:

```
string js = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/JavaScript.js"));
       jsDiv.InnerHtml = js.Replace( "{{mydata}}",getJSONdata() );
```

Javascript:

```
var mydata ={{mydata}};
```

Using the String.Replace method to change {{mydata}} to a json data in C#,and I've seen another way like this:

```
string js="var mydata="+getJSONdata()+";"
jsDiv.InnerHtml = js;
```

but in the JavaScript.js file I have about a hundred lines of codes,if using the second way could be very long C# string....
so I'm thinking if save those lines of javascript codes in a .js file then read it,change the string .

Comment: Side note: it is very nice to know that there are still people who can easily understand code that creates code that creates code that later send to browser to be parsed.... (I'm not one of those people and really wish code and data never mixed in such a painful to understand way)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sometimes it is inevitable, e.g. when you are doing some crazy metaprogramming and generating code based on the metadata.

Comment: You';d be better off keeping your JavaScript code static, and putting dynamic content in the page(s) as necessary for the JavaScript to find. Then you can import your JavaScript via `<script src=code.js>` tags, and clients can cache the code.